# Localization not working for buttons in mvc4 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, jquery-jtable

I localized my application and it works well for labels,title and error messages.i have used jtable in my application.But buttons are not getting localized.Inside jtable.js i have

```
messages: {
            serverCommunicationError: 'An error occured while communicating to the server.',
            loadingMessage: 'Loading records...',
            noDataAvailable: 'No data available!',
            areYouSure: 'Are you sure?',
            save: 'Save',
            saving: 'Saving',
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            error: 'Error',
            close: 'Close',
            cannotLoadOptionsFor: 'Can not load options for field {0}'
        }
```

But if i select russian i should get these messages in russian language.For that I have tried to add resource file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $.widget("hik.jtable", {
        messages: {

            serverCommunicationError: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.serverCommunication',
            loadingMessage: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.loading',
            noDataAvailable: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.noData',
            areYouSure: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Sure',
            save: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Save',
            saving: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Saving',
            cancel: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Cancel',
            error: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Error',
            close: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Close',
            cannotLoadOptionsFor: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.cannotLoad'

        }
    });
});
```

But it is not working..How can i pass current culture to js file and call resource file within it.

Pls help in localising buttons..

EDIT:-

I created a class

```
public static class MyGlobals
   {
       public static string serverCommunicationError;
.....
   }
```

and inside view i gave like this.

```
@SEFTool.Models.Administration.MyGlobals.serverCommunicationError= '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.serverCommunication'
```

Am geetin the russian language inside '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.serverCommunication' .But this value is not getting passed to  @SEFTool.Models.Administration.MyGlobals.serverCommunicationError.serverCommunicationError is showing null

EDIT:-

Inside index view i have done like this.....But am not getting output

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

(function (global) {
    var r = global.Resources || {};
    r.serverCommunicationError = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.serverCommunication)';
    r.loadingMessage = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.loading)';
    r.noDataAvailable = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.noData)';
    r.areYouSure = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Sure)';
    r.save = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Save)';
    r.saving = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Saving)';
    r.cancel = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Cancel)';
    r.error = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Error)';
    r.close = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Close)';
    r.cannotLoadOptionsFor = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.cannotLoad)';

    global.Resources = r;
})(this);

    $('#content_1').jtable({
        title: '',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        sorting: true,
        inlineEditor: false,
        permissions: 'AED',
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or just the default english buttons?

Comment: Chips_100: if i give like this serverCommunicationError: '@SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.serverCommunication',     the button content is @SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.serverCommunication

Comment: so, it seems like it is not evaluating the c# code. are you actually in an mvc view, where you can use this razor syntax (the @ sign)? the file ending should then be `.cshtml`.

Comment: @Chips_100 No..the code is inside a javascript file..is there any option to pass current culture to js file and call resource file within js file

Comment: I guess an option you could solve this is the following: store your localized strings into a js variable in the .cshtml file (you should have a view somewhere, right?) and then reference that variable in your .js file. if you want to know more about this approach, i could provide a more detailed answer (i will write one if you are interested)

Comment: @Chips_100 yes i want a more detailed answer..it will be a great help for me..

Answer (score 0):

In your view (.cshtml), set up the following script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(global) {
        var r = global.Resources || {};
        r.serverCommunicationError = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.serverCommunication)';
        r.loadingMessage = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.loading)';
        r.noDataAvailable = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.noData)';
        r.areYouSure = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Sure)';
        r.save = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Save)';
        r.saving = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Saving)';
        r.cancel = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Cancel)';
        r.error = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Error)';
        r.close = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.Close)';
        r.cannotLoadOptionsFor = '@Html.Raw(SEFTool.Resources.Models.ValidationStrings.cannotLoad)';

        global.Resources = r;
    })(this);
</script>
```

Then, in your script file, reference it like this:

```
messages: {
            serverCommunicationError: Resources.serverCommunicationError,
            loadingMessage: Resources.loadingMessage,
            noDataAvailable: Resources.noDataAvailable,
            areYouSure: Resources.areYouSure,
            save: Resources.save,
            saving: Resources.saving,
            cancel: Resources.cancel,
            error: Resources.error,
            close: Resources.close,
            cannotLoadOptionsFor: Resources.cannotLoadOptionsFor
        }
```

Just remember that the first script tag has to be called before the code in you js-file, so that the `Resources` object will be available. If, in your js-file, you wait for the DOM to be ready, this will be no problem though.
Also, this is just the first solution that came to my mind. Maybe its not the best, and someone else knows a better approach. I would be interested too in different ways to solve this.

Comment: Just remember that the first script tag has to be called before the code in you js-file, so that the Resources object will be available-i didnt understand this

Comment: You need to make sure that the first code snippet will be run before the second one. so, you have to include it before your external js-file with the second code snippet, because the second code snippet references the object that is created by the first one.
if you run the second code on DOM - ready, it will be no problem though, because that would always run after the first code snippet (which runs immediately and does not wait for the dom to be ready)

Comment: So, what do you see now? have you updated the code in your script file to use my provided second code snippet?

Comment: Do you get an error in your browser console? (F12)?
Sounds like there is a javascript-exception...

Comment: I got it..I just called resource file inside  '$('#content_1').jtable({ '  and it works fine.